# How to display image in website using storage for laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

In my Laravel project, which I was coding on my old computer, I used to store my images in the "store" folder and used "php artisan storage:link" to display them on my pages. However, after copying the same project to my new computer, when I save an image, it goes to "storage/app/public" instead of "public/storage," causing the images not to display on the web.
How can I fix this?

When I run "php artisan storage:link," it tells me that it already exists.

Comment: Delete the symbolic link: rm public/storage. Then recreate it: php artisan storage:link. To display the image: <img src="{{ asset('storage/image.jpg') }}" alt="Image">